# Check If Magento Product Has Thumbnail

Tags: magento

I want to display a thumbnail image on a product page only if it exists.  Currently it shows the placeholder image if a thumbnail image is not selected.  I suppose I need to just wrap that around an if statement but do not know the method (if there is one) to check if the thumbnail image exists. Here is the code used to display the thumbnail:

```
<img id="slide-img-1" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(163, 100); ?>" /></a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the following:

```
<?php if(!($_item->getThumbnail() == "no_selection")): ?>
    <div class="image-holder">
        <img class="thumbnail-image"
            src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->constrainOnly(true)->resize(800); ?>"
            alt=""
            title="" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

If a thumbnail exists for the product then it should be set on the `$_product` instance. So you can use that in your condition, see below.

```php
<?php if($_product->getThumbnail()): ?>
    <img id="slide-img-1" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(163, 100); ?>" /></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Great! That worked perfect.  But I decided a different approach to avoid interfering with the thumbnail image.  I created a custom Image attribute.  I figured changing out the thumbnail with the attribute name would work, and it did.  But now I need to check if that custom image attribute has an image attached, otherwise the product page throws an error. Here is the updated code.`<img id="slide-img-1" src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'brand_logo') ?>" />`